# How do I convert a Polars DataFrame to Vec<RecordBatch>?

Tags: rust, apache-arrow, rust-polars, apache-arrow-flight, apache-arrow-datafusion

edit: To hopefully be more concise, how do I do this?-

```
use polars::prelude::{DataFrame, NamedFrom, df};
use arrow::record_batch::RecordBatch;

fn main() {

    let polars_df: DataFrame = df!("cat_data"     => &[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
                                   "dog_data"     => &[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
                                   "giraffe_data" => &[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]).unwrap();

    let batches: Vec<RecordBatch> = polars_df/*  ???????   */;

    for batch in batches {
        println!("{:?}", batch);
    }
}
```

---

initial post:

How can I start with a [Polars DataFrame](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.DataFrame.html) instead of the Datafusion DataFrame used below where the results variable will evaluate to [`Vec<arrow::record_batch::RecordBatch>`](https://docs.rs/arrow/latest/arrow/record_batch/struct.RecordBatch.html)?

`let results = df.collect().await.map_err(to_tonic_err)?;`

This is the [`collect`](https://docs.rs/datafusion/latest/datafusion/dataframe/struct.DataFrame.html#method.collect) function used above from Datafusion.

Generally, I've tried and failed to solve this by using iterators like [`iter_chunks()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.DataFrame.html#method.iter_chunks) and [`iter_chunks_physical()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.DataFrame.html#method.iter_chunks_physical).

For broader context, I am working on a Polars implementation of arrow flight via [this datafusion example](https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion/blob/e676f3c114ce00972b4bfb68c4e0a87e500a2286/datafusion-examples/examples/flight_server.rs#L102).

Comment: check and link to the rust doc of the Dataframe creates you mention.

Comment: Thanks! Are those links more helpful?